# Bandwidth Issues

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently having issues on almost all of our Magento sites where they are hitting their bandwidth limit.

What could be causing the issue or is it just an issue that comes with using Magento?

Comment: Are they on the same server?  Does the amount of traffic you have make sense for the bandwidth limit - As in, is it justified to hit the limit?  We can't give you an accurate answer if we do not have stats.

Comment: I am getting of the same issue on my website, As already we have set the limit but again it shows the same issue after a few days kindly advise me what should i do solve it
[https://flowerportal.in/](https://flowerportal.in/)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146106)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're hitting the bandwidth limit or are you getting a 508 Resource limit error? This is most likely if you are on a shared hosting platform, a software called "Cloudlinux" runs on shared servers that protects other users from your site consuming too many resources. This one is most often caused by bots or automated scrapers with fake user agents crawling your site rapidly. It's very common these days and with the fake user agents, it can be difficult to block.

If you are getting a bandwidth issue, then it's possibly a good thing, it means you're getting traffic. Talk to your hosting provider about increase your bandwidth.

Comment: It's always been a bandwidth limit error we've been getting. I don't think the traffic would cause this issue. We have one site that's using on average 4gigs a month while we have 3 other sites that are using around 35-40 gigs a month. One of our sites is currently on pace to use around 50 gigs this month. We're not entirely sure what's causing this issue but we've just been increasing the bandwidth limit anytime it's exceeded.

Comment: You'd need to get the data from the access logs to see more details what the webserver has been serving. You might have access to webalizer or similar depending on your hosting provider. One that could consume bandwidth could for example be that you are accitentally serving hi quality images for email advertising of course the most obvious is just traffic increase but does for example google analytics help on confirming it. But without actual request data its impossible to get the cause of "excessive" bandwith usage; you are just guessing.